# how to print lines between two time stamps using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to filter out lines between two timestamps and print those lines only in Python?

Example: I want to filter 08:00:00 am to 05:00:00 pm I tried some thing like this, but it's not working.

```
 def ipaddr(w):
    print("====Welcome to HTTP log Debugger ==== ")
    file= input("Please Enter log File path: ")
    start_time = input("start Time: ")
    End_time = input("End Time : ")
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for L in lines:
        if L.startswith(start_time):
            p= 1
        elif L.startswith(End_time):
            p=0
            break
        if p: print(L)
```

Comment: provide sample input data. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And be more specific than *"it's not working"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
D1 = 1 #starting date

D2 = 10 # for ending date

clock1 = 8 # for 8'O clock
clock2 = 17 # for up to 17:59::59 

month_int = 1 # for jan
Clock= "{0:0=2d}".format(D1)

for i in range(clock1+1,clock2):
    Clock = Clock+"|"+"{0:0=2d}".format(i)


import calendar
month = calendar.month_name[month_int]

s= "{0:0=2d}".format(D1)

for i in range(D1+1,D2):
    s = s+"|"+"{0:0=2d}".format(i)

with open('logfile.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
            if re.match("\D{3}\s"+month+"\s("+s+")\s("+Clock+")", line):
                print line
```

Comment: i got a new scenario that what if date is string format say 
ex : Mon May 03  12:23:11: 
       Tue  May 04  11:00:10:
i want both date and time need to filtered and print necessary line

Comment: as per I updated you will get from `08:00 to 16:59` from may 3rd to 6th

Comment: As it is hard coded .. i need user input which should be generic can you help me out plz

Comment: you can try two loops one for date and other for time filtering. And you need to standardize time formate

Comment: @RAM I updated code for you. only drawback is it only find in same calendar month

Comment: i'm trying ... it worked only for one month that to May . if i change the month in the code again then it is not working.
let me clear . in the above code it is for month jan . i changed to may i.e 5 , i created logfile with both jan and May, i ran script for may it worked. then i changed and ran for Jan . it didn't worked

Comment: i'm trying to understand the flow and debug the issue.

Comment: @RAM I got your issue. Your logs month formate is different from what  u get in `calendar.month_name[]`  For `calendar.month_name[1]` will return `January`.. For abbreviation you can use  `calendar.month_abbr[1]` it will return `Jan`